# Activate a single ELPA package out of many

Tags: emacs, elpa

I want to start Emacs from a clean state and activate only one package in `~/.emacs.d/elpa/`, not all of them. Specifically, I need to load a bleeding-edge version of Org-mode, while clean Emacs loads the built-in version. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Emacs from a clean state, provide a `-Q` option:

```
emacs -Q
```

Then run command `eval-expression`, usually <kbd>M-:</kbd>, and enter the following Lisp expression:

```
(let ((package-load-list '((org t)))) (package-initialize))
```

`package-load-list` variable holds packages that will load and activate when `package-initialize` is called. It's a list of pairs in the form of `(PACKAGE VERSION)`. You can put `t` instead of `VERSION`, and the newest version will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
emacs -Q -l ~/.emacs.d/elpa/org-bleedingedge/org-autoloads.el
```

should do it.  Of course, if that "org" package requires others, it won't magically handle those dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that [How to start up emacs with different configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21568042/how-to-start-up-emacs-with-different-configurations) covers this. Create a new Emacs sandbox, install any packages you need, and you can run it side-by-side with your normal configuration.